# How can I make emacs-jedi use project-specific virtualenvs

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv, jedi

I would like emacs-jedi to detect when I am editing files in different projects, and use the corresponding virtualenv if it is available. By convention my virtualenvs have the same name as my projects. They are located in `$HOME/.virtualenvs/`

I found [kenobi.el](http://yergler.net/blog/2013/07/28/emacs-jedi/) but it assumes that virtualenvs are found in the bin directory in the project root. It also has a couple of other features that I don't need at all.

With inspiration from kenobi.el, I wrote the following initialisation for jedi. It works pretty well, but not perfectly.

If I import library `A` from my project, and `A` imports `B`. I am able to jump into definitions defined by `A`, but once there, I'm not able to continue jumping into definitions from `B`.

My initialisation:

```lisp
(defun project-directory (buffer-name)
  (let ((git-dir (file-name-directory buffer-name)))
    (while (and (not (file-exists-p (concat git-dir ".git")))
                git-dir)
      (setq git-dir
            (if (equal git-dir "/")
                nil
              (file-name-directory (directory-file-name git-dir)))))
    git-dir))

(defun project-name (buffer-name)
  (let ((git-dir (project-directory buffer-name)))
    (if git-dir
        (file-name-nondirectory
         (directory-file-name git-dir))
      nil)))

(defun virtualenv-directory (buffer-name)
  (let ((venv-dir (expand-file-name
                   (concat "~/.virtualenvs/" (project-name buffer-name)))))
    (if (and venv-dir (file-exists-p venv-dir))
        venv-dir
      nil)))    

(defun jedi-setup-args ()
  (let ((venv-dir (virtualenv-directory buffer-file-name)))
    (when venv-dir
      (set (make-local-variable 'jedi:server-args) (list "--virtual-env" venv-dir)))))

(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi-setup-args)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
```

What is wrong with how I initialise jedi?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have now settled on a solution that uses the [virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el) ELPA package to activate virtualenvs, allowing emacs-jedi to pick up the virtualenv path from the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable.

Here is a complete, working, emacs-jedi initialisation:

```lisp
(defun project-directory (buffer-name)
  "Return the root directory of the project that contain the
given BUFFER-NAME. Any directory with a .git or .jedi file/directory
is considered to be a project root."
  (interactive)
  (let ((root-dir (file-name-directory buffer-name)))
    (while (and root-dir
                (not (file-exists-p (concat root-dir ".git")))
                (not (file-exists-p (concat root-dir ".jedi"))))
      (setq root-dir
            (if (equal root-dir "/")
                nil
              (file-name-directory (directory-file-name root-dir)))))
    root-dir))

(defun project-name (buffer-name)
  "Return the name of the project that contain the given BUFFER-NAME."
  (let ((root-dir (project-directory buffer-name)))
    (if root-dir
        (file-name-nondirectory
         (directory-file-name root-dir))
      nil)))

(defun jedi-setup-venv ()
  "Activates the virtualenv of the current buffer."
  (let ((project-name (project-name buffer-file-name)))
    (when project-name (venv-workon project-name))))

(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi-setup-venv)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
```

Remember that you have to install virtualenvwrapper first.

Read the [virtualenvwrapper documentation](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el) for an alternative way of automatically activating project virtual evironments. In short you can create a `.dir-locals.el` file in the root of your project, with the following content:

```lisp
((python-mode . ((project-venv-name . "myproject-env"))))
```

Change `"myproject-env"` to the name of your virtualenv and activate the virtualenvironment using the `python-mode` hook:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (hack-local-variables)
                              (venv-workon project-venv-name)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
```

Comment: There is another nice package auto-virtualenvwrapper: https://github.com/robert-zaremba/auto-virtualenvwrapper.el  . I think you shall try it.